# Escape comma in regexp using negative lookbehind

Tags: regex, perl

In Perl, I need to split a string around commas. However, the string itself can contain commas, which should not be split around. Those commas are escaped with backslash. My question is: how to write the splitting regexp?

I currently have:

```
/\s*(?<!\\),\s*/
```

however, this does not remove the backslash.

From string

```
 apples, pears\, yellow, pears\, green
```

I want to get

```
apples
pears, yellow
pears, green
```

But I get

```
apples
pears\, yellow
pears\, green
```

How to remove the backslash?

Comment: Matching doesn't change the text being matched!!

Comment: !ikegami No, but matched string is not included in splitting.

Comment: huh? `split` returns the specified pieces of the matched string. Why would `split` remove backslashes without you asking?

Comment: @ikegami it removes the whitespaces and the comma, I suppose those are matched, too.

Comment: Seriously? `split` returns portions of the string completely unedited. And again, why would it be even remotely acceptable for `split` to remove backslashes without being asked?

Comment: @ikegami Well if I was not interested in modified string, I would not bother splitting it, would I? The regexp used for splitting IS NOT part of the split string. But in case of this lookbehind, that portion of the regexp is preserved, which is my issue. Can you make the regexp better, so it takes the lookbehind as part of the split regexp, so the resulting string doesn't contain it?

Comment: Re" Well if I was not interested in modified string, I would not bother splitting it, would I?" Sure you would! It makes no sense to use `split` to modify a string, so you would most definitely use it even if you didn't want to modify a string.

Comment: Re "Can you make the regexp better,", No. Like I said, it's impossible because `split` doesn't remove anything. It just returns the parts found between the separators. It would make no sense for `split` to start removing stuff from the parts you asked to return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative to using `split`, you can use [`Text::ParseWords`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aParseWords) to allow for embedded or escaped delimiters:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Text::ParseWords;

my $str = 'apples, pears\, yellow, pears\, green';
my @list = quotewords('\s*,\s*', 0, $str);
print Dumper \@list;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'apples',
          'pears, yellow',
          'pears, green'
        ];
```

Edit: Adding `\s*` to the pattern will allow you to remove excess whitespace where you do not want it. Also note that the second argument is `0` to remove delimiters and backslashes.

As a sidenote, if you want to simply delete backslashes, you can use transliteration or substitution:

```
$str =~ tr/\\//d;
$str =~ s/\\//g;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried ParseWords, but they preserve the whitespaces.

Comment: They only preserve whitespace if you tell it to. If you use the pattern `\s*,\s*` it will count the whitespace as part of your delimiter (and remove it).

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using ParseWords as you suggested.